# Why EF Code First performance drops dramatically when using bidirectional relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I had a hard time figuring out how to title the question, because the problem is really odd.

I have a Code First to existing database Entity Framework classes. Let's limit them to the two that are relevant:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Now I run the code

```
using(var context = _contextFactory.GetContext())
{
    var t1 = context.Groups.ToList();
    var t2 = context.Products.ToList();
}
```

it runs just fine, populating the lists in few seconds (Products table is quite big).

But if I uncomment commented line, something odd happens. `t1` is populated as usual but `t2` takes tens times longer. If I swap `t1` and `t2` assigning, then `t2` runs fast and `t1` runs for ages.

It looks to me like EF is doing something in `Context` behind the scenes and has problem with this relation somehow. Anyone else had this problem or know the explanation? I use EF for quite a long time now and never saw this behavior.

In SQL database there is a relation between `Product` and `Group` configured.

Comment: Is lazy-loading enabled?

Comment: Yes lazy-loading is enabled, but when I load the tables separately, they work just fine. The problem occurs only if I load both of them.

Comment: Sounds like time is consumed for building the relations between objects in the context. Do you try domething like: `var v1 = context.Groups.Include("Products").ToList(); var v2 = v1.SelectMany(x => x.Products).Distinct();` ?

Comment: I just tried `context.Groups.Include("Products").ToList()` and this line was very slow (I stopped waiting after 2 minutes, normally getting `Products` is about 8 seconds). That made me think about indexes in Products table. I'll add index on FK to Groups and let know.

Comment: Didn't help. Still terribly slow. To add some info: the count of `Groups` is 26, and count of `Products` about 150 000.

Comment: Just run SQL query from linqpad as you suggested (I was already using linqpad for testing times of execution). The query which is corresponding to `.Include` one took 2 seconds and returned 155k results.

Comment: for me it is the materialization of the relation: EF has to check 150 000 * 26 case to update a in memory relation table

Comment: But I'm pretty sure that in the same project I wrote EF queries before, that returned almost a million of rows, were joining several tables and done all of this in few seconds. I also don't understand why it's so slow even if I don't use `.Include()` so it shouldn't mind related entities.

Comment: From here, imho, I can imagine several solutions: try loading by pieces (`.take(1000)`), materialize a DAO class (`.select(x => new DAO {})`), or question yourself : do I really need 150000 pocos in my application serveur memory ?

Comment: I you have time you can dl the EN project from codeplex and do some perf test... results would be welcome.